# C# HttpWebRequests 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, instagram, webrequest, http-status-code-403

after hours of trying I decided to ask you for help.
I am trying to send a post request to a website (https://www.instagram.com/)
More exactly here: "https://instagram.com/web/likes/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/like/"
The problem doesn't always appear, for example I can succesfully send the request 4-5 times, and then I get this error 3-4 times, then I can send it again etc.
That's why I can't understand what's causing the problem.
My code:

```
byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
HttpWebRequest postReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com/web/likes/" + ID + "/like/");
WebHeaderCollection postHeaders = postReq.Headers;
postReq.Method = "POST";
postReq.Host = "instagram.com";
postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0";
postReq.Accept = "*/*";
postHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
postHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
postHeaders.Add("X-Instagram-AJAX", "1");
postHeaders.Add("X-CSRFToken", CSRF);
postHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
postReq.Referer = "https://instagram.com/";

postReq.CookieContainer = cookies;

postReq.KeepAlive = true;

postHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
postHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
postReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream postStream = postReq.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
postStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse postResponse;
postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

**ID** is a 26 characters number, always different for each photo.
I got the headers using **Live HTTP Headers**, and they are the same like my request. 
This is the full error description: 
"**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help :).

Comment: Maybe it's a built in protection to prevent "like" abuse on their side.

Comment: @McGaz I can manually send more requests using the browser and it works fine. I did some tests using **Tamper Data** and I edited some headers, I saw if you edit the **Refer** Header I get the same error, but this makes no sense, cause I always use the same Refer in the request and sometimes it works sometimes not.

Comment: You probably need to close your HttpWebResponse (and everything else). I expect it is holding open connections to you and denying you more than 4 or 5 until one times out and then it will allow another connection in its place.

Comment: @McGaz Sadly it's giving me the same error. Thanks for the help you are giving me :)